# Is there a tool to show schema/definition changes between two dump files for MySQL?

Tags: mysql, percona, mysqladmin

The purpose is that if there are any table alter changes or new tables added, they should be picked up by python script set in cron and a mail should be sent.

The idea is that the script would be taking a schema-only backup using mysqldump and comparing it with an older dump file using a tool.

I tried using diff but as it shows only the lines that changed and not the table name (as expected) it's not useful in my case.

```
$ diff -y --suppress-common-lines file1.sql file2.sql

`name` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL     |     `name` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL
```

mysqldiff tool was discontinued so wondering if there is any other tool that can do this?